# Factoring $x$ out of $(x+dx)$

Tags: calculus, factoring

I am going through Calculus Made Easy and I am on the Case of the Negative Exponent question.

My question is how is the $x$ factored out of $(x+dx)$ in the formula below? Could someone breakdown the steps to factor $(x+dx)$?

$$(+)=\left[\left(1+\frac{}{}\right)\right]$$

Comment: You will need to improve your algebra skills in order to tackle calculus. Try it with numbers: Factor $2+4=2(1+?)$; $2+5=2(1+?)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I would argue that he's aware of that as he's asking a question to improve his algebra skills... To verify the formula works, try multiplying the products on the right hand side to see if you end up with what you have on the left.

Comment: This is known as the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of multiplication.

Comment: Of course, the problem is $dx$ is not really a number. What $dx$ "really is" is a bit hard to describe in beginning calculus, so early on  we sometimes treat it as a number.

Answer (score 3):

@cstandley is correct but let me be more explicit:

$$(x + dx)= \frac{x}{x}(x + dx) = \frac{x(x + dx)}{x} = x\left(\frac{x + dx}{x}\right) = x\left(\frac{x}{x} + \frac{dx}{x}\right) = x\left(1 + \frac{dx}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The given expression is $(x + dx)$. To factor $x$ out of this expression, we need to express it as a product of $x$ and some other term. Let's do that step by step:

1. Start with the expression: $(x + dx)$
2. We want to factor out $x$, so we look for a common factor in both terms. In this case, it's $x$ itself.
3. Divide both terms by $x$ to find the other factor: $\frac{x}{x} + \frac{dx}{x}$
4. Simplify the fractions: $1 + \frac{dx}{x}$
5. Now, combine the factored term $x$ with the simplified expression to get the factored form: $x(1 + \frac{dx}{x})$

So, factoring $x$ out of $(x + dx)$ results in $x\left(1 + \frac{dx}{x}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact question from the book and it was really hard to find the answer.  I couldn't figure out how the $x$ got into the denominator. Factoring out $x$ wasn't in my memory.  Mathway and other math answers software treats dx as a variable so it takes it to d.   So,
$x(\frac{dx}{x})=dx$    and of course $x(1)$ is $x$.  You probably have the answer by now, but I empathize.
It is absolutely amazing to me how, that when you ask a question, you get every answer ever thought of except the one you want.

Comment: I think you can safely delete all the text except "x(dx/x)=dx and of course x(1) is x"

Comment: Sorry for airing my frustration.